# Inserting a Binary Tree in a vector

Tags: c++, binary-tree

What I would need is pushing the binary tree in a vector and write out the vector`s contents in the terminal to prove that is works.

I cant seem to make it work , I tried in a few different ways like making funcions that will do that for me. Im a Computer Science student so Im kinda beginnerish , I tried my hardest but I just dont know how to do it.

You gave me a lot of good advice through your posts and answers but, I didn`t find anything in this regard so Im asking for your help.

Here is my binary tree :

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <math.h>

using namespace std;

class Binfa {
public:
int value;
Binfa *left;
Binfa *right;

int depth() {
    int leftd = 0, rightd = 0;
    if (left == NULL && right == NULL)
        return 1;
    if (left != NULL)
        leftd = left->depth();
    if (right != NULL)
        rightd = right->depth();
    return (max(leftd, rightd) + 1);
}

static double averagedepth(Binfa *node) {
    static int db = 0, sum = 0, depth = 0;
    if (node != NULL) {
        ++depth;
        Binfa::averagedepth(node->right);
        Binfa::averagedepth(node->left);
        --depth;
        if (node->left == NULL && node->right == NULL) {
            ++db;
            sum += depth;
        }
    } else {
        return 0.0;
    }
    return (double) sum / db;
}

static double spread(Binfa *node, double average) {
    static int db = 0, depth = 0;
    static double sum = 0.0;
    if (node != NULL) {
        ++depth;
        spread(node->right, average);
        spread(node->left, average);
        --depth;

        if (node->right == NULL && node->left == NULL) {
            ++db;
            sum += ((depth - average) * (depth - average));
        }
    }
    if (db > 1)
        return sqrt(sum / (db - 1));
    return sqrt(sum);
}

static void print(Binfa *node) {
    static int idepth = 0;
    if (node != NULL) {
        ++idepth;
        print(node->right);
        for (int i = 0; i < idepth; ++i)
            printf("---");
        printf("%c(%d)\n",
                node->value < 2 ? '0' + node->value : node->value,
                idepth - 1);
        print(node->left);
        --idepth;
    }
}
};
int main(int argc, char **argv) {
char b;
int in = 0;
int i, egy_e;
Binfa *root = new Binfa();
root->value = '/';
root->left = root->right = NULL;
Binfa *current = root;
if (argv[1] != NULL) {
    in = open(argv[1], O_RDONLY);
}

while (read(in, (void *) &b, 1)) {
    for (i = 0; i < 8; ++i) {
        egy_e = b & 0x80;
        if ((egy_e >> 7) == 1) {
            if (current->right == NULL) {
                current->right = new Binfa();
                current->right->value = 1;
                current->right->left = current->right->right = NULL;
                current = root;
            } else {
                current = current->right;
            }
        } else {
            if (current->left == NULL) {
                current->left = new Binfa();
                current->left->value = 0;
                current->left->left = current->left->right = NULL;
                current = root;
            } else {
                current = current->left;
            }
        }
        b <<= 1;
    }
}
printf("\n");
Binfa::print(root);
printf("melyseg=%d\n", root->depth() - 1);
printf("altag=%f\n", Binfa::averagedepth(root));
printf("szoras=%f\n", Binfa::spread(root, Binfa::averagedepth(root)));
return 0;
}
```

Comment: You have to be much more specific about what you're asking.

Comment: To store something in a vector (or any other Standard Library container) the thing you are storing generally needs to be copyable and assignable.

Comment: Do you need to make copies of the binary tree?  Usually one instance is enough.

Comment: My teacher only gave me these informations , to make a binary tree , that one  i`ve done , and to put it in a vector the only help I got was to make the tree constructor part make a copy that is placed in the vector , but I honestly do not understand why or how.
I`m sorry if you can`t help me based on these informations, but I understand it`s not much to go on.

Comment: So as far as I understand your comments  i need to make a copy and put that in a vector , how would that work ?

Comment: My thought would be just to do a in-order traversal of your tree and `.push_back()` each node value to your vector to fill it. Then you can simply use a range-based iterator to display the values in the vector.

Comment: I would love to be able to do that but as I said Im a beginner sadly so I dont understand how that works yet , I just looked it up and I dont really know how to use it just by that.